# How to set DNS IP address using Windows Server 2008

Tags: dns, nslookup

I am using Windows Server 2008 and set the DNS IP address to `192.168.2.10` From my Ethernet adapter properties (Internet Protocol Version) but when type `nslookup` is shows `127.0.0.1` which is default DNS IP address. Why it does not show `192.168.2.10`?

Comment: Exactly which version and edition of Server 2008 are you using?  Is it configured to be a Domain Controller?  Are the DNS server services enabled on to local machine?  After changing the DNS in your adapter settings, did you try rebooting and trying NSLookup again?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hi an d thanks the version is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64Bit Update 2014

Comment: Are the DNS server services enabled on to local machine ? No, I just try to configure my 2008 server and also Yes I try to configure that as a domain contoler

Comment: When you type NSLOOKUP the computer will query the DNS servers it has access to in the order shown in IPCONFIG /ALL. Please use this command and see what it reports under DNS.

Comment: @DanielK It reposts my domain name

Comment: You are looking for something like "DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.220.220  208.67.222.222"